# Reference Request: LP representation of problems

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, linearization

I am preparing for an exam on Linear optimisation and came across different problems where some apparently non linear problems can be modelled as LP (For example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1150022/a-linear-program-for-maximizing-a-fraction), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4423477/how-to-build-an-explicit-polyhedral-representation-of-p-n) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4423477/how-to-build-an-explicit-polyhedral-representation-of-p-n)). I was wandering if there is a reference which contains all the commonly used techniques that are used for this kind of questions. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The Mosek modeling cookbook has a chapter about it https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/linear.html#linear-modeling